# Why does my TV not show the mediafiles provided by DLNA?

Tags: smart-tv

I got a telefunken-TV (Model: A50U445A) and a Symology NAS DS218+

I use the built-in media server on the NAS to publish mediafiles (movies) via DLNA in my wlan.

The TV shows the NAS, it shows the folders provided by DLNA but it does not show the files.

When I copy the files onto a USB-Drive the TV can play them, no problem.

When I use the media player of the PC which is connected to the same router as the NAS and the TV (but via LAN) the files are visible and I can play them.

So, why the TV does not show the files provided by the mediaserver?

Comment: Are you sure the TV supports what ever format the media files are stored in?

Comment: @hardillb: Yes I do. Because over the USB-drive I can watch the same files (see question). But anyway. I found the problem and will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the "." in the nameing of the files. The files were named e.g.:

"Doctor Who (2005) - S01E01 - Rose.720p.x264 AC3.mkv"

I renamed them to e.g.:

"Doctor Who (2005) - S01E01 - Rose_720p_x264 AC3.mkv"

and viola: It worked!